# Resizing Tiff Image increasing the file size using C#

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, system.drawing

I am trying to change the resolution of my tiff file, it was successfully changed using the below code, but It was increasing my output filesize from 74kb to 828kb after drawing

Code Used:

```
    public void Resize(string imageFile, string outputFile, int width,int height)
    {
        using (var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
        {
            var newWidth = (int)(width);
            var newHeight = (int)(height);

            using (var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight))
            {
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {           
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.None;

                    graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));

                    newImage.Save(outputFile,ImageFormat.Tiff);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tiff file format is a lossless format, so to reduce the size you need to use compression such as Lzw.

So you need to include these details when you save the file.

```
ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");

System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression;
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
```

And the Helper function to get the encoder

```
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
{
    int j;
    ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
    encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
    {
        if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
            return encoders[j];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Full code and more details can be found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No while using  Graphics.FromImage(FileName) is increasing the file size,after using the encoder parameters also.

Comment: What are your old & new sizes?  Is the input also in TIFF format, if so what compression is used?